# How can I append template arguments repeatedly to a type?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a metafunction, `Append` that takes a templated type and adds `N` number of arguments of type `T` to the template, for example, if I call `Append<2, int, std::tuple<>>` I want to get `std::tuple<int, int>`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
#include <tuple>                                                                

template <int N, typename T, template <class> class Seq, typename... Args>      
struct Append;                                                                  

template <int N, typename T, template <class> class Seq, typename... Args>      
struct Append<N, T, Seq<Args...>>                                               
{                                                                               
    using type = Append<N-1, T, Seq<Args..., T>>::type;                         
};                                                                              

template <typename T, template<class> class Seq, typename... Args>              
struct Append<0, T, Seq<Args...>>                                               
{                                                                               
    using type = Seq<Args...>;                                                  
};                                                                              

// create a big tuple with N number of "int" types in it                           
using T = Append<2, int, std::tuple<>>::type;                                      

int main()                                                                         
{                                                                                  
    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

However, when I try to compile this I get:

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list
>   for ‘template class Seq, class ...
>   Args> struct Append’

What am I missing?

Comment: *error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template* at `Seq<Args...>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few small errors that I will explain below. This works:

```
#include <tuple>                                                                

template <int N, typename T, typename SeqWithArgs>      
struct Append;                                                                  

template <int N, typename T, template <typename...> class Seq, typename... Args >      
struct Append<N, T, Seq<Args...> >                                               
{                                                                               
    using type = typename Append<N-1, T, Seq<T,Args...> >::type;                         
};                                                                              

template <typename T, template<typename...> class Seq, typename... Args>              
struct Append<0, T, Seq<Args...> >                                               
{                                                                               
    using type = Seq<Args...>;                                                  
};                                                                              

// create a big tuple with N number of "int" types in it                           
using T = Append<2, int, std::tuple<> >::type;                                      

static_assert(std::is_same<T,std::tuple<int,int>>::value,"Didn't work");

int main()                                                                         
{                                                                                  
    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

One problem was in your unspecialized template class: You want it to have three arguments, the third of which is actually a type and not a template class (compare your call with `tuple<>`). That was the reason for the error you got, because you passed a type where the compiler was expecting a template.

Then, for the specializations, you now want to deduce the template template argument, so there the four template parameters with the template and its template arguments separated into `Seq` and `Args` were actually correct. However, it has to be a variadic template class (not only `template <class> class Seq` as in your question), because otherwise, adding the template arguments one after another would fail at the second iteration.

Then, finally, you need a `typename` in front of the dependent name `Append<[...]>::type`.